# XPath query for Google Sheets ImportXML to get YouTube video URL And Subscribe count from page

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, youtube

I am trying to import YouTube Subscribe count and Channel URL but it is not working.

I able to import **Video View** by this  `//*[contains (@class, 'view-count')]` https://prnt.sc/rjcw27

But when try to get the Channel URL form the YT video it does not work. https://prnt.sc/rjcvbm
    =+importxml("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLuR-4YxEns","//*[contains (@class, 'yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string')]")

Here's what I tried too:

```
=//yt-formatted-string[@id='text']/a/@href
="//*[contains (@class, 'style-scope ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer')]"
=//*[contains (@class, 'yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string')]"
=//*[@id="subscriber-count"]
```

**Could someone please help?**

Comment: Supposing your Youtube urls are in A2 cells, use `=IMPORTXML(A2;"//span[@class='yt-subscription-button-subscriber-count-branded-horizontal yt-subscriber-count']")`for the number of suscribers and `=IMPORTXML(A2;"concat('https://www.youtube.com',//a[@class='yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link']/@href)")`for the channels urls. Output : https://framapic.org/eRjDTGCZMPN6/9UHOrmBC3zB7.PNG

Comment: Thanks a lot, E.Wiest really its work... can i ask you where did you get the class 
"yt-subscription-button-subscriber-count-branded-horizontal yt-subscriber-count" 
OR 
"yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link"?

Comment: I get it after downloading and parsing the page in R. Otherwise, just look at some github projects. They maintain up to date xpaths to scrape Youtube content.